# "Дон Жуан" - почему неправильно?

Tags: транскрипция

Понятие "донжуан" уже вошло в поговорку, но вот мне интересно, почему изначально стали произносить это имя неправильно? Насколько мне известно, сам дон Жуан (don Juan) был испанцем, а в испанском языке буква J читается как Х. То есть, он дон Хуан, а вовсе не Жуан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Литературный образ дона Хуана был создан Тирсо де Молиной в пьесе El burlador de Sevilla у convidado de piedra («Севильский распутник и каменный гость»). Сюжетом пьесы послужила подлинная история дона *Хуана* Тенорио, жившего во времена кастильского короля Педро I Жестокого. То есть истоки образа, действительно, испанские. Но уже через три года после издания пьесы Тирсо де Молины Жуан шёл со значительным успехом на народных сценах Италии. Там он назывался доном Джованни (исп. Don Juan, итал. Don Giovanni). Итальянская переделка, более придерживавшаяся исп. оригинала, до нас не дошла; но по ней написаны первые пьесы о доне *Жуане* во Франции, куда сюжет был занесён ок. 1658 г. Именно на основании этих ранних источников Мольер написал свою пьесу «Дон Жуан, или Каменный пир» (D. J. ou le festin de pierre, поставлена в 1665), в которой впервые лишил героя отличительных особенностей его испанского происхождения и ввёл в пьесу французскую действительность своего времени. Он отбросил внесённый итальянцами комизм и уничтожил клерикальный оттенок, характеризующий пьесу Тирсо. И уже из французского театра дон **Ж**уан вышел на широкие подмостки Европы и далее. Кстати, у Пушкина в "Каменном госте" героя зовут Гуан, что значительно ближе к испанскому оригиналу.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь очевиден примат испанского языка, и по-испански это имя звучит "Хуан", и никак иначе. Звук "ха" здесь слышен вполне четко и недвусмысленно для любого иностранца, поэтому употребление звука "же" или "ге" (то есть, произношение имени дон Жуан или дон Гуан) совершенно неправомерно. Полагаю, давно пора внести коррективы при переводе на русский язык и считать устаревшими(архаичными)  прежние произношения. Аналогично назрела необходимость подправить произношения (как можно ближе к оригиналу) и некоторых других иностранных слов (особенно имен, названий городов,географических мест и др.) Например, произносить Хитлер, Хамбург, Стокхолм, Рома, Наполи   (вместо Гитлер, Гамбург, Стокгольм, Рим, Неаполь). Наверное, было-бы неплохо широко обсудить все это на форуме